# Swap two object when they are on two different list

Tags: c#

In my example I got 8 Objects.

Assume that first element of BlueList is refered to Element1 and first element of RedList1 is also refered to Element1

[image]

Now I want to swap Object1 with Object3, but when I make something like this:

Pseudo Code:

```
Object Temp = BlueList1[0];
BlueList1[0] = BlueList[1];
BlueList1[1] = Temp;
```

The result is:

[image]

Because I only switched list refferences. 
How to safety swap two addresses of object, like in picture below? As You can see Element1 is switched with Element3.

[image]

It could be easly done in C++. Is it posible in C#?

Comment: because you changing the value not reference list is reference type.

Comment: I think you need to show more code in order to understand if elements refer to other elements, or only lists refer to elements. I don;t understand how the red list refers to Element 1 and Element 2 at the same time. Also is everything the same type or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make a wrapper class.

```
class Element<T> {
    public T Object { get; set; }
    public void SwapWith(Element<T> other) {
        // warning: this is not thread-safe
        T tmp = other.Object;
        other.Object = this.Object;
        this.Object = tmp;
    }
}
```

Then you can make change like

```
BlueList1[0].SwapWith(BlueList[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need also to change the reference in RedList1 and RedList2

```
RedList1[0] = Element3;
RedList2[0] = ELement1;
```

Answer (score -1):

> because you changing the value not reference because list is reference
>   type so you need to change the reference so create one method   like
>   that do looping and call that method and pass your values.

```
void swap(int ref a , int ref b)
    { 
    int temp =a;
        a=b;
       b =temp;
    }
```

> Hope it will be helpful for you Thanks

Comment: Are you quoting someone else? Why are you using _blockquotes_ in your post?